# Select em um servidor, insert em outro

Tags: mysql

Utilizo a seguinte query para selecionar dados de um banco e inserir em outro:

```
insert into banco_novo.cliente (codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, data_nascimento, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, cep)
select codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, IFNULL(sexo, 'I'), IFNULL(data_nascimento, '2000-01-01'), endereco, bairro, cidade, IFNULL(estado, '0'), cep 
from banco_antigo.cliente
```

Preciso agora fazer o select num banco de um servidor e inserir noutro banco em outro servidor.
Tentei assim:

```
insert into servidor_novo.banco_novo.cliente (codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, data_nascimento, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, cep)
select codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, IFNULL(sexo, 'I'), IFNULL(data_nascimento, '2000-01-01'), endereco, bairro, cidade, IFNULL(estado, '0'), cep
from servidor_antigo.banco_antigo.cliente
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Estou com o workbench conectado com os dois servidores, porém não sei como executar a query para fazer esta operação.

Comment: Tentou `INSERT INTO bancox.tabela (SELECT * FROM bancoy.tabela)`?

Comment: Dois bancos no mesmo servidor é OK. Mas dois bancos em dois servidores diferentes que é o BO

Comment: Agora que entendi. Entendi 2 bancos, não 2 bancos em servidores separados. 

Comment: Para servidores diferentes não vai funcionar diretamente. Você terá que extrair os `inserts` e executar na outra conexão.

Comment: [Será?](https://sites.google.com/site/silviogarbes/sistemas/mysql/criacao-de-link-remoto-no-mysql-federated-semelhante-ao-dblink-do-oracle)

Comment: Se deseja rodar a queries em databases diferentes, não seria o caso de apenas utilizar a clausula "use database1" e depois "use database2". antes da querie que vai rodar?

Comment: @RafaelSalomão Numa query só eu consigo fazer isso ?

Comment: @RafaelSalomão, o que ele precisa é servidores diferentes e não somente bancos diferentes.

Comment: É porque não entendi, é duas databases no mesmo servidor ? Ou dois bancos distintos um em cada servidor ? Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Nesse caso em servidores distintos teria que ter duas conexões distintas!

Comment: @rbz, nunca usei esse `link`, sempre que precisei fazer alguma coisa parecida, fiz via Excel ou extraindo os `inserts`, mas parece ser uma saída, inclusive irei salvar o link nos favoritos.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Eu também não! Se fizer testes, depois me fala?

Comment: te aviso no chat.